# Which Eclipse project type do I need, to use existing code and generate a makefile

Tags: eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I am confused by Eclipse project types. Ideally, I want to build from existing sources (which have no makefile) directly on disk **and** to have Eclipse generate a makefile.

Can that be done?

If not, can I create a C++ project, import my existing files, work on them and later export the files plus a makefile which Eclipse generated for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your project type is not `Makefile Project`, I guess eclipse can generate a makefile. But you have to edit the tool chain to use `GNUMake`. If you use the default setttings with `current builder = CDT internal builder`, no makefile is generated, select `current builder = GNU make`, you should see the makefile in the debug folder. (go to menu `project` -> `properties`, select `Tool Chain Editor` then select `Current Builder` = `Gnu Make Builder`.)